# How does the scope of structures, unions, etc work when functions are involved?

Tags: c

I recently came across structures and some things aren't quite clear. Let's say that I've got a program like this:

```
struct num print_a(struct num c); 

int main(){
  struct num{
    int a;
    int b;
  }c = {1, 2};
  struct num d;
  d = print_a(c);
}

struct num print_a(struct num c){
  printf("%d", c.a);
  return c;
}
```

Would this work or do I have to declare struct num outside of main? Because how can my function print_a "see" what struct num means (the type that it has to return) as it's declared outside of its scope?

Sorry if the question is dumb

Comment: With `struct num print_a(struct num c)` you tell the compiler that function `print_a` has a parameter of type `struct num` that we call `c` in the remainder of the function. It has nothing to do with any `struct num` called `c` elsewhere in the source code.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes `struct num` should be decalred outside of `main` because the definition does not exist outside of main.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie would it be different if the function didn't return any value? If it was of type void and took just c as a parameter, would I still need to declare it outside of main?

Comment: Of course you would. The function needs to know the definition of the struct it takes as parameter, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Alright thanks a lot!

Comment: @4386427 I wanted to know the "theory" behind it, my book always made it sound like they were declared in main and would then work in functions called outside of main, so that gave me some doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this work or do I have to declare struct num outside of main?

Well, why not simply try it out?

http://ideone.com gives:

```
Compilation error #stdin compilation error #stdout 0s 9424KB
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:11:15: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
   d = print_a(c);
               ^
prog.c:11:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct num’
   d = print_a(c);
   ^
prog.c:10:14: warning: variable ‘d’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   struct num d;
              ^
prog.c: At top level:
prog.c:14:31: error: parameter 1 (‘c’) has incomplete type
 struct num print_a(struct num c){
                               ^
prog.c:14:12: error: return type is an incomplete type
 struct num print_a(struct num c){
            ^~~~~~~
prog.c:14:12: error: conflicting types for ‘print_a’
prog.c:3:12: note: previous declaration of ‘print_a’ was here
 struct num print_a(struct num c);
            ^~~~~~~
prog.c: In function ‘print_a’:
prog.c:16:10: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void
   return c;
          ^
prog.c:14:12: note: declared here
 struct num print_a(struct num c){
            ^~~~~~~
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ gives:

```
main.cpp: In function 'main':
main.cpp:13:15: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
   d = print_a(c);
               ^
main.cpp:13:7: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct num'
   d = print_a(c);
       ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:12:14: warning: variable 'd' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   struct num d;
              ^
main.cpp: At top level:
main.cpp:16:31: error: parameter 1 ('c') has incomplete type
 struct num print_a(struct num c){
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~^
main.cpp:16:12: error: return type is an incomplete type
 struct num print_a(struct num c){
            ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:16:12: error: conflicting types for 'print_a'
main.cpp:5:12: note: previous declaration of 'print_a' was here
 struct num print_a(struct num c);
            ^~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function 'print_a':
main.cpp:18:10: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void
   return c;
          ^
main.cpp:16:12: note: declared here
 struct num print_a(struct num c){
            ^~~~~~~
```

Hmmm... kind of give us the answer: **no - it will not work**

When you define the struct inside main, it is only known inside main. If you want to use the struct outside main you have to move the definition of the struct out of main - like:

```
struct num {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct num print_a(struct num c); 

int main(){
  struct num c = {1, 2};
  struct num d;
  d = print_a(c);
}

struct num print_a(struct num c){
  printf("%d", c.a);
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The declaration

   ```
   struct num print_a(struct num c);
   ```

   at the beginning of the example code tells the compiler that:

   - You promise to define a `struct num` at file scope. For the moment, the compiler labels `struct num` as an *incomplete type*, which can be used in (some) declarations, for example, to declare (but not to *define*) functions, and to declare or define *pointer* types and variables. The compiler won't hold you to this promise unless you actually try to use the type `struct num`.

     You *must* complete the definition of `struct num` *before* using that type in a definition or in a declaration where its size matters.
   - You promise to define a function named `print_a` taking a `struct num` and returning a `struct num`. The compiler won't hold you to this promise unless you actually try to use this function -- if you don't actually call it anywhere in the program, the compiler will forgive an unfulfilled promise.
2. The `struct num` defined inside the function `main` has nothing to do with the incomplete `struct num` at file scope. You are of couse allowed to go ahead and define it, but it will *shadow* the file-level `struct num`.
3. The statement

   ```
   d = print_a(c);
   ```

   inside function `main` is incorrect, and will cause the compiler to generate several error messages, because it breaks the promises you made. Specifically, the compiler will complain that you are trying to use the incomplete type `struct num` declared at file scope as if it were complete. Remember that the `struct num` defined inside `main` has nothing to do with the `struct num` at file level.
4. The function definition

   ```
   struct num print_a(struct num c){ ... }
   ```

   is incorrect, because you have not kept your promise to define the type `struct num`. That inside `main` there is *another type* named `struct num` doesn't count; that type is usable only inside `main`.

To correct the program you need to move the *definition* of `struct num` before `main`. It can come before or after the *declaration* of `print_a`.

Comment: I wonder about "_You promise to define a_ `struct num`" because the compiler now needs to generate the code to return a complete structure. Your statement would be OK if it concerned a _pointer_.

Comment: The compiler *does not need* to generate the code, unless the program actually calls the function. If the program actually calls the function, and at that point the type is still incomplete, the compiler will complain loudly; this falls under "try to use the type" in my answer; point 3.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: And how is this different from what I said? I said that the definition of `struct num` can come before or after the *declaration* of the function, not the definition.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Point 1, first bullet, lists the legal uses of the incomplete type.

Comment: The bullet doesn't make explicit it must have been completely declared _before_ first use. The bullet allows to declare it after use, which generates an error.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Edited.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: In `struct num func(struct num arg)`, the `struct num` in `struct num arg` refers to the `struct num` in `struct num func()`. See https://ideone.com/clJk1X for an example. (Yes, if it was `int func(struct num arg)` the type would be uncompleteable. But it isn't.)

Comment: Sorry, I focused on the parameter and missed the prior declaration.